# cl.exe flag or setting to disable tail call optimization at /O1 or higher (equivalent to gcc -fno-optimize-sibling-calls)

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I work on a project where we maintain our own stack crawler (for various reasons).  We need to be able to crawl the stack with a certain amount of reliability.  At the moment we're hitting an issue where a function tail calls to a function that we're interested in, and our stack trace skips a frame that would be present in a debug build (/Od).  We already disable frame pointer optimization and inlining (/Oy- and /Ob0) so we can get better stack traces, but we still want to be able to turn on some optimizations (/O1) to make the code faster.  However, tail calls still interfere with our stack traces.

Is there any flag or setting that will disable this optimization in MSVC?  gcc has -f(no-)optimize-sibling-calls, which covers this.

Comment: Do you need it for production as well as for testing?

Answer (score 0):

No, you could possibly put your tail-calling function in a separate compilation module and only compile it without optimisations though.